# Risky to fetch Stripe API directly

Tags: react-native, security, stripe-payments, expo

I am trying to find a solid, scalable way of integrating stripe into a react native (managed workflow with expo) app for android & iOS.

There are several options. E.g.:

1. [tipsi/stripe](https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/)
2. [expo/payments](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments/)
3. Directly communicating with the stripe API (e.g. as described in this [blog post](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html))

I would like to go with option 3 as it's the one with the fewest overhead and most flexible (you don't need to eject expo, etc.). Now my question is, **are there compliance/ security issues when directly calling the stripe API in a production mobile app?** (Given the fact that payments need to follow a lot of restrictions and are a highly sensitive topic)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, handling raw credit card details in your application puts it in PCI compliance scope (https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance under Mobile SDKs). If it all possible I'd recommend using Stripe's native SDKs, even through a wrapper like tipsi, or use WebViews. 
"[If you write] your own code to handle card information, you may be responsible for additional PCI DSS requirements (6.3 - 6.5) and not be eligible for an SAQ A. [..] we’d suggest you reach out to a PCI Qualified Security Assessor (QSA) to determine how best to validate your compliance."